# where to put swap ? partitioning a drive for ubuntu and spare ntfs space

Tags: partitioning, swap

I have a spare hard drive.
 I am not setting up dual boot.
 I have ubuntu  on ext4 at the start of the drive.
and want to put a ntfs partition and a swap space
 should I put swap space between ubuntu and ntfs or at the end of drive?

Answer (score 1):

It actually doesn't matter.

As long as you don't need to move Ubuntu or Windows, you're fine.

Just add it where you have free space. :)